# Is it possible to use Phusion Passenger Enterprise and Phusion Passenger Open source for same app but different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Phusion Passenger Enterprise is awesome but their per server license is expensive if there are many job servers (say 10+). I was thinking of using Phusion Passenger Enterprise for one or two app server where http requests will hit and Phusion Passenger Open source on all job servers. It is possible and does it violate Phusion Passenger Enterprise license ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passenger author here. Yes it is possible and it doesn't violate the license. [Here is an example for Heroku](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-ruby-heroku-demo#using-passenger-open-source-in-development-enterprise-in-staging-and-production) but the concept is applicable generally.